# Javascript form duplicate

Tags: javascript, forms, duplicates

I am trying to duplicate that Director / Member form. I want add button to just add another member, and delete to erase last entry. Code seemed to work at some point, but does not anymore. Do not remember what I have changed. Add button works just fine, but delete button is just disabled. And if I purposely enable it, it does not work the right way.

Directors / Members

```
        <hr>
        <b>Corporations:</b> Please list each director of the company.<br>
        <b>LLCs:</b> Please list each member (owner) of the company.<br>
        <b>Non-Profits: </b> Please enter information for at least three (3) unrelated directors if filing for 501(c)(3) status.<br>
        <br>

        <?php $y=0; $clone =1;  do{ ?>

            <div id="<?php echo "clonedSection$clone"; ?>" class="clonedSection" >

                <p><label id="<?php echo "member_label$clone"; ?>"  >  <?php echo "Director / Member $clone"; ?></label> </p>
                <p>First name:<input type="text" name="member_firstname" id="member_firstname" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][0];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_first_name"];?></span> </p>
                <p>Last name:<input type="text" name="member_lastname" id="member_lastname" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][1];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_last_name"];?></span> </p>
                <p>Street address:<input type="text" name="member_address" id="member_address" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][2];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_address"];?></span> </p>
                <p>City: <input type="text" name="member_city" id="member_city" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][3];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_city"];?></span> </p>
                <p>State:<select name="member_state" id ="member_state">
                    <?php //$states = listStates(statesList());
                    foreach($states as $value){
                        echo '<option >'.$value.'</option>';
                    }  echo '<option selected>'.$split_members[$y][4].'</option>'; ?>
                </select> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_state"];?></span> </p>
                <p>ZIP code:<input type="text" name="member_zip" id="member_zip" value="<?php echo $split_members[$y][5];?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $member_errors[$y]["member_zip"];?></span> </p>

            </div>
        <?php $y++; $clone++;}while($y < count($split_members)); ?>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another member" />
            <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove member" />
        </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {



        $("#btnAdd").click(function() {



            var num = $(".clonedSection").length;
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

            var newSection = $("#clonedSection" + num).clone().attr("id", "clonedSection" + newNum);

            newSection.children(":nth-child(1)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_label" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(2)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_firstname" + newNum).attr("name", "member_firstname" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(3)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_lastname" + newNum).attr("name", "member_lastname" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(4)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_address" + newNum).attr("name", "member_address" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(5)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_city" + newNum).attr("name", "member_city" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(6)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_state" + newNum).attr("name", "member_state" + newNum);
            newSection.children(":nth-child(7)").children(":first").attr("id", "member_zip" + newNum).attr("name", "member_zip" + newNum);


            $(".clonedSection").last().append(newSection);

                elem = document.getElementById('member_label' + newNum);
                elem.innerHTML = "Director / Member " + newNum;

                elem = document.getElementById('member_firstname' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_lastname' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_address' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_city' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_state' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";
                elem = document.getElementById('member_zip' + newNum);
                elem.value = "";


            btnDelete = document.getElementById('btnDel');
            btnDelete.attr("disabled","");
            //$("#btnDel").disabled = false;
            alert(newNum);



            if (newNum == 12)
                $("#btnAdd").attr("disabled","disabled");
        });

        $("#btnDel").click(function() {

            var num = $(".clonedSection").length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have

            $("#clonedSection" + num).remove();     // remove the last element
            // enable the "add" button
            $("#btnAdd").attr("disabled","");

            // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
            if (num-1 == 1)
                $("#btnDel").attr("disabled","disabled");

        });

        $("#btnDel").attr("disabled","disabled");
        var count = $(".clonedSection").length;
        if (count > 1)
            $("#btnDel").attr("disabled","");
            //$("#btnDel").disabled = false;

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is _"it does not work the right way"_?

Comment: when I enable it, just to try clicking on it to see what it does... it removes last element and when it is down to 1 first element, it disables itself and add button for some reason. Anyways, I need it disabled for first time page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.prop("disabled",false);` and `.prop("disabled",true);` instead of

`.attr("disabled","");` and `.attr("disabled","disabled");`

Comment: I will try that, but I just thought of other possible issue. Should I put my script in the end? I put it in the end after </html> tag. When I put it in the head it does not work at all

Comment: Nothing should be after `</html>`. Your script is in `$(document).ready()` it should be fine anywhere in the `<head>` after `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: ok thank you, but I just discovered a new problem. Now buttons work fine. When I click submit, it submits everything just fine. it also prints out the form with that do loop, but if I want to submit everything again it submits only the last member. It seems like a logical errors, but everything looks fine because it prints everything back through the loop. Should I open a new Question here?

Comment: The `name` attr in the form must be unique. Check your html, if you have `<input>`s with `name="member_address"` and not `name="member_address[x]"` where x is 0 to count-1,  your form is bad.